# Pandas: Remove Rows Where the Value of One Column Appears on Any Row in Another

Tags: python, pandas

Example data is:

```
000000008,2, 1,000000010
000000009,1, 1,000000011
000000010,1, 1,000000008
000000011,2, 1,000000032
000000012,3, 1,000000009
000000013,2, 1,000000108
```

You can see that some values in the first column also appear in the fourth column. I want to remove those rows, where the value in the fourth column also appears on any row in the first column.

Therefore, in this example, following rows should be removed:

```
000000008,2, 1,000000010
000000010,1, 1,000000008
000000012,3, 1,000000009
000000009,1, 1,000000011
```

Code starting point:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T = u'''000000008,2, 1,000000010
    000000009,1, 1,000000011
    000000010,1, 1,000000008
    000000011,2, 1,000000032
    000000012,3, 1,000000009
    000000013,2, 1,000000108'''

from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(T), header=None)
print(df)
```

Comment: Why is that last row removed?

Comment: You guys are right, I made a mistake with the output -- fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, from your description, you can do:

```
df[~df.iloc[:,3].isin(df.iloc[:,0])]
```

Which returns:

```
    0  1  2    3
3  11  2  1   32
5  13  2  1  108
```

Contrary to your desired output, this removes the row with `000000011`, but not the one with `000000108`, because `000000011` is found in both columns, but `000000108` is not

Comment: Why does this work if the data type is an integer but not if the data type is a string?

Comment: It works with strings, but your way of reading it in with `StringIO` includes all the whitespaces in your string `T`